# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageView

Tags: ios, exception, compiler-errors, iboutlet

I have a problem with the RootViewController of my application. When I run the app I get this error. What do it means?

```
  NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x8634010> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:     this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bigImageView.'
 First throw call stack:
 (0x1992012 0x1357e7e 0x1a1afb1 0xe04711 0xd85ec8 0xd859b7 0xdb0428 0x4bc0cc
 0x136b663 0x198d45a 0x4babcf 0x4bc98d 0x29eceb 0x29f002 0x29ded6 0x2af315 0x2b024b 
 0x2a1cf8 0x1dbedf9 0x1dbead0 0x1907bf5 0x1907962 0x1938bb6 0x1937f44 0x1937e1b 0x29d7da 0x29f65c 0x2c6d 0x2b95)   
 libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

My code in RootViewController.h

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


  @interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{

  }

 @property (nonatomic, copy)IBOutlet UIImageView * bigImageView;
 @property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL fromRootViewController;


 - (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;



 @end
```

My code in RootViewController.m

```
   #import "RootViewController.h"
   #import "MenuViewController.h"

  @interface RootViewController ()

   @end

  @implementation RootViewController

  @synthesize bigImageView;
  @synthesize fromRootViewController;

  - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
        [super viewDidLoad];
         UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation];

          if(deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || deviceOrientation==    UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    self.bigImageView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"milanocina_V.png"]];

}
else if (deviceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
   self.bigImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"milanocina_O.png"]];

}
else if (deviceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){

    self.bigImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"milanocina_O.png"]];



}

[self.view addSubview:self.bigImageView];

UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
recognizer.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

}
```

The RootViewController initially called ViewController and I've changed the name. Can be correlated with error? What can I do?

Comment: Did you notice that the error message says that you are trying to set that property on `UIApplication`...All the code in the world on `RootViewController` won't make a difference.  I bet there is a faulty link in your XIB file.  Bad links will show up with little explanation points.

Comment: How di I find the bad connection?

Comment: I don't know if this is causing your problem, but you're doing something wrong with bigImageView. You define it as an IBOutlet, but then assign it to instances created in code. If you're hooking it up in IB to an ImageView you have there, then the code will override that. It probably shouldn't be an IBOutlet, since you need it to be different things depending on orientation.

Comment: So how can I fix the viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another possibility: You renamed your class, but forgot to change your UIViewController initialization code. For me, it was this:

```
NewViewController *vc;
vc = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OldViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Once I replaced the string @"OldViewController" with @"NewViewController", the problem went away.

Answer (score 27):

At some point, you set a `@property`.  You then deleted it from your code but didn't unhook it in your xib/storyboard.  You need to find it in your storyboard, rightclick it, and delete the outlet.